# How to use different function to replace an item in list?

Tags: python

Noob here, I'm trying to learn how different functions and their contents relate to each other.

I have a list:

```
files = ["cheese.png","grapes.png","blueberries.png"]
```

I would like the printmessage to print:

```
["cheese.png","grapes.png","BLUEBERRIES.PNG"]
```

By using different functions like so:

```
class Ding:

    def __init__(self):
        files = ["cheese.png","grapes.png","blueberries.png"]
        self._filenames = files
        self._newFilename = "BLUEBERRIES.PNG"
        self._blueberries = self._filenames[2]
        
    def renamer(self):
        for x in self._filenames:
            if x == self._blueberries:
                x.replace(self._blueberries, self._newFilename)
        
    def printmessage(self):
        print(renamer(self))

Ding().printmessage()
```

You can use [**this W3S applet**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_ref_super) to replace and test out the code above (the code doesn't function yet, I'm doing something wrong, that's for sure) - I'm getting error: *NameError: name 'renamer' is not defined*

Comment: What makes you think that you are "doing something wrong"?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the comment. Because I get errors that I can't solve...

Comment: Please describe the errors. Quote them, show the undesired result and compare it to the desired one (which you should also show).

Comment: Note that `x.replace(self._blueberries, self._newFilename)` returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of self._blueberries has been replaced by self._newFilename.  Since this copy is not set to anything, self._blueberries is left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrylG - But I don't get it... "Since this copy is not set to anything"

Comment: @ManuJärvinen--strings are immutable, so operations on strings return a new string rather than modifying the string in place.

Comment: Do this has to be a closed question? I think I explained things clearly and got a clear answer, don't you think?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. If you don't understand how to use methods of a class, this is something that is best addressed by studying the language fundamentals, not by asking here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for the clarification - but I used a whole lot of time for searching but couldn't find good fundamentals for this topic :( - W3S is the best resource I got, but didn't have this info in my mind (or then I just didn't find it there)

Comment: Weird. When I put `python class tutorial` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+class+tutorial), the [first result](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) I get is from the official Python web site's own tutorial; and when I scroll down to where it says [method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) (or search for `method` and skip through a bit) I find the relevant information right there, including examples. What specific search queries did you try? Or what difficulties did you have understanding the results you found?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for pointing that out. I admit those tutorials are good, but still not as noob friendly as W3S is. But good, I try to use that as my reference from now on also and try my best to understand it. (But still, imo, StackOverflow could consider broadening its scope to noob-friendly stuff as well :/ - just my 2 cents)

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't intend to exclude beginner level material. It's just that everything that fits the format has been asked already. The goal here isn't to help people understand existing material; the goal is to *generate material that doesn't exist yet*, so that *when people use a search engine they can find a high-quality result here*. Our idea of high quality is explicitly *not* conversational or "friendly" because it's only possible to be social with the OP, while many people will read the question later.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks, yes. But I think you can be high quality even if the material exists somewhere else. Hmmh. I just think that people like me could find this answer also and benefit from it greatly. Even if it has been explained differently in other places and manuals. - We can go to chat to talk more or leave this as is, both are fine by me. (I'm glad I got the answer to the question, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is simple;

You are calling `renamer` wrongly.

It should be `self.renamer()` not `renamer(self)`;

Another thing here is your `renamer` will not work as you are not updating the list.

Here is the complete solution;

```
files = ["cheese.png","grapes.png","blueberries.png"]


class Ding:

    def __init__(self):
        files = ["cheese.png","grapes.png","blueberries.png"]
        self._filenames = files
        self._newFilename = "BLUEBERRIES.PNG"
        self._blueberries = self._filenames[2]
        
    def renamer(self):
        return [file.upper() if file == self._blueberries else file for file in self._filenames]
        
    def printmessage(self):
        print(self.renamer())

Ding().printmessage()
```

You should now understand how class methods work. We need to access them as `self.method_name()` as they are not independent functions but class methods.

Comment: Yes @Yunnosch true, while this is super good info, I'm trying to just learn those basic function-related things...

Comment: Done! And I tested that the upmost line isn't even required :)